# WSO2 BAM: howto send log event via REST endpoint

Tags: rest, wso2, wso2-bam

I want to send log events to BAM 2.4.1 via client REST but I dont find any example about it so I need to know what is the endpoint url and some example about building of the json message to send.

Thanks in advance for any help

Answer (score 0):

Currently, it doesn't have a REST API to publish events. Current options are listed [here](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS310/Publishing+Data+to+DAS).

In addition you can use [Analytics JavaScript (JS) API](https://docs.wso2.com/display/DAS310/Analytics+JavaScript+%28JS%29+API) as well. It has this limitation.

> Currently due to a limitation, client applications should be deployed
>   in the same domain as the Dashboard server. i.e -
>   DAS_HOME/repository/deployment/server/webapps

Comment: Sorry but I'm using BAM 2.4.1.  and from the wso2 docs  ([link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/BAM241/Sending+Events+through+the+REST+API) ) I read thath is possible to send event by rest client